CSL/Pandoc omitting reference that doesn't have a page number
I am using CSL ( pandoc with the citeproc option), and I need to cite general references to works without always including a page number. When I do this, the output either has the reference entirely omitted or it is using the digit 1 (which sometimes also formats as a numeric list).
This error then causes every other reference to the same work to fail (title replaced with 1) and the work is also omitted from the bibliography.
Here's the markdown, using Better Bibtex:
[^fn1]: @gcs1897, 68.
[^fn2]: @achelis1897, 116.
[^fn3]: @achelis1897. See also...
[^fn4]: @bardenhewer1877, 33.
Here's what I'm getting:
1. Hippolytus, Exegetische Und Homiletische Schriften, 1897, 68.
2.  1, 116.
3.
   1.    See also...
4. Otto Bardenhewer, Des heiligen Hippolytus von Rom Commentar zum Buche Daniel: ein literärgeschichtlicher Versuch (Freiburg im Breisgau: Herder, 1877), 33.

In this example, the citation in footnote 3 was to the work as a whole with a comment afterward. Footnote 2 refers to the same work, with a page number, but it now errors. Footnotes 1&4 to different texts work as expected.

can you post the CSL JSON or BibLaTeX (whichever you're using in your pandoc document) for the @achelis1897 item? It looks like it might just be a broken reference somehow?

@adam.smith, appreciate the suggestion. Tarleb's answer below has fixed the problem (and I had tested adding and removing page numbers, so I was fairly sure the reference itself worked).

You're running into issues because the syntax of citations and example lists overlap. Disable support for that extension and the problems should go away:
pandoc --from=markdown-example_lists ...

